# Angular scope, ng-repeat, and calling method on ng-click

Tags: button, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm a self taught novice programming working on developing a web application using node, angular, bootstrap, and the graph database neo4j.

I'm hoping to get some pointers on what I'm doing wrong in the following code.

Broken HTML:

```
<div class='btn-group'  ng-controller="typeCtrl" ng-repeat="type in display">
<button class='btn' ng-click='whatsmyname(type)' > {{type}}</button>
    <button class='btn dropdown-toggle dropdown'><span class='caret'></span></button>
<ul class= 'dropdown-menu'>
  <li><a>Exclue Term</a></li>
  <li><a>Exclue and Load</a></li>
  <li><a>Include</a></li>
  <li><a>Include and Load</a></li>
</ul>
<p>Hello? {{display}}</p>
```

Angular Controller:

```
function typeCtrl($scope){
    var theList = [];
    var alltheterms;
    var things = [{"name":"Image","tags":["Type","Image","Core"]},{"name":"GIF","tags":["Type","Image"]},{"name":"Infographic","tags":["Type","Image"]},{"name":"Chart","tags":["Type","Image"]},{"name":"Photo","tags":["Type","Image"]},{"name":"Microscope","tags":["Type","Image"]},{"name":"Telescope","tags":["Type","Image"]},{"name":"Text","tags":["Type","Text","Core"]},{"name":"Article","tags":["Type","Text"]},{"name":"Short Story","tags":["Type","Text"]},{"name":"Quote","tags":["Type","Text"]},{"name":"Podcast","tags":["Type","Audio"]},{"name":"Audio","tags":["Type","Audio","Core"]},{"name":"Video","tags":["Type","Video","Core"]},{"name":"Map","tags":["Type","Image"]},{"name":"Website","tags":["Type","Core","Website"]}];
    var core = [];

    var filterData = function(data){
             for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                 if (data[i].tags.indexOf("Core") > -1){
                     theList.push(data[i].name);
                 }
             }
             alltheterms = data;
             core = theList
             $scope.display = theList;
         };

 $scope.whatsmyname = function (value){
        $scope.value = value;
        theList = [];
        for(var i=0;i<alltheterms.length;i++){
            if (alltheterms[i].tags.indexOf(value) > -1){
                theList.push(alltheterms[i].name);
            }
        }
        var notAgain = theList.indexOf(value);
        theList.splice(notAgain,1);
        $scope.display=theList;
    };   
    $scope.reset = function(){
      $scope.display = core;
    }
  filterData(things);
```

}

[Link to Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5PnB5A)

I'm confused as to why the simple example calls the function and the more complex example does not. Note that on my machine the complex example at least shows up correctly- I must have made an error in translating it into the plunker. As I understand it is probably related to scope, but I can't tell what exactly is going on. Any advice (directly related to this question as well as general advice) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It be great if you could add the code here.

Comment: Added it- and figured out the issue at the same time. I needed to include a div outside of the current one and to identify the controller there.